# "Error response from daemon: lstat ...: no such file or directory" starting a Docker container

Tags: docker

Getting the following error when starting container `/usr/bin/docker run ac-jenkins`

```
docker: Error response from daemon: lstat  /var/lib/docker/overlay/
2704cc8045d14ab55f87e85913e17fd0a190aa1b89927630deccfcf5b8d05dc7: 
no such file or directory.
```

Comment: This might be useful https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396

Answer (score 0):

try to run Jenkins docker by the following command it will run it properly

```
docker run -d -p 9090:8080 -p 50000:50000 -u root -v $PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the below error,

```
`Error response from daemon: mkdir /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/************: no such 
file or directory`
```

This was due to space unavailability. In windows, i had docker installed in C drive, it worked after deleting unwanted files and cleaned up disk space.

Try to increase the space of the directory where docker is installed.